# Regular Expression in Java: Pattern.compile( "J.*\\d[0-35-9]-\\d\\d-\\d\\d" )

Tags: java, regex, syntax

I found a code in Java Regular expression which is confusing to me:

```
Pattern.compile( "J.*\\d[0-35-9]-\\d\\d-\\d\\d" );
```

The string to be compiled is:

```
String string1 = "Jane's Birthday is 05-12-75\n" + "Dave's Birthday is 11-04-68\n" + "John's Birthday is 04-28-73\n" + "Joe's Birthday is 12-17-77";
```

What does it mean by the

```
[0-35-9]
```

And why there are 4 "\d"s instead of 3? I assume there are only 3 numbers in the birthday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form of `\\d` simply matches a digit, not a number.

So using the pattern of `\\d\\d` will match two consecutive digits.

Using `\\d\\d-\\d\\d` will match two consecutive digits, a `-` literally, two consecutive digits.

Let's take a look at your match and why.

```
Joe's Birthday is 12-17-77
                  ^          match a digit 0 to 9
                   ^         match any character of '0' to '3', '5' to '9'
                    ^        match a '-' literally
                     ^       match a digit 0 to 9
                      ^      match a digit 0 to 9
                       ^     match a '-' literally
                        ^    match a digit 0 to 9
                         ^   match a digit 0 to 9
```

The `[0-35-9]` part matches any character of `0` to `3`, `5` to `9`

Your whole regular expresson explained:

```
J              'J'
.*              any character except \n (0 or more times)
\d              match a digit 0 to 9
 [0-35-9]       any character of: '0' to '3', '5' to '9'
   -            match a '-' literally
  \d            match a digit 0 to 9
  \d            match a digit 0 to 9 
   -            match a '-' literally
  \d            match a digit 0 to 9
  \d            match a digit 0 to 9
```

Answer (score 2):

`\\d` does not match a number, it matches a digit. The distinction is that `\\d\\d` will match two consecutive digits.

`[0-35-9]` will match a digit in the range `0-3` or a digit in the range `5-9`.

The practical upshot is that this matches a birthday where the month is 10, 11, 12, 01, 02, 03, 05, 06, 07,  08, or 09. The day and year don't matter provided they are two digits. It is a very long-winded way of saying "find me any birthday that was not in April (`04`)".

Answer (score 2):

> What does it mean by the `[0-35-9]`:

It means that you are providing a [set of characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) enclosed within square brackets. It specifies the given characters that will successfully match a single character from a given input string. So the above class of characters will match if the matching character is among `0` through `3`, or `5` through `9`, inclusive .

> And why there are 4 "\d"s instead of 3? I assume there are only 3
>   numbers in the birthday.

Your birthday string portion is: `Birthday is 05-12-75`:

`\d` is a [predefined character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) where `\d` represents a digit, and `\d\d` represents two consecutive digits. Hence for a date `xx-xx-xx-xx` we would write, `\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d`, where `x` is assumed to represent a digit(`0-9`)

Answer (score 1):

The confusion arises in the way we perceive numbers. To our mathematical eye, it looks that the middle section is a single number, the number "35". But in actuality, it is two numbers, a "3" and a "5". As has been answered in depth previously, this is actually two ranges, the range of digits from 0 through 3 inclusive, and the range 5 through 9 inclusive, thus eliminating 4 from the possible digits it will match.

As to the number of "\d"s, there are actually 5 not 4. The first one pairs with a single digit from the ranges of digits to match a month (for example, October is 10 and June is 06, so both match, while April, which is 04, does not). the next two "\d"s pair up to be a day. The last two pair up to make a year.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is true but I think there is a mistake with the first two digits of the date.

> (Month value is should be 01-02-03-05-06-...-12)

```
\\d[0-35-9]
```

This regex provides all months except April but it must be 0-12 intervals, at the same time.

So, the correct regex is must be below;

```
(0[0-35-9]|1[0-2])
```